# Hive posexplode for uneven values

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql, explode

I have the following scenario

```
id            date                   issue1    issue2     issue3    issue4     issue5
1   01APR1995~31JAN1992~01JAN1990     0~0~1     1~1~1     0~1~0     1~0~0      0~0~0
2   01APR1996~31JAN1994~01JAN1992     0~0~0     1~0~0     1~1~1      0~0~1     0
```

The following result I need

```
id       date              Issue1   Issue2   Issue3   Issue4    Issue5
1      01JAN1990            1         1       0        0         0             
1      31JAN1992            0         1       1        0         0
1      01APR1995            0         1       0        1         0
2      01JAN1992            0         0       1        1         0
2      31JAN1994            0         0       1        0         null
2      01APR1996            0         1       1        0         null
```

I tried the following code, but for some reason, the ID = 2 is only giving me a single record

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by  ID order by n1 desc) as seq_num 
from ( 
select id, n1, date,issue1, issue2,issue3, issue4,issue5  
from 
(select * from 
(select distinct 
a.id,
split(a.date,'\\~') c1,
split(a.issue1,'\\~') c2, 
split(a.issue2,'\\~') c3, 
split(a.issue3,'\\~') c4, 
split(a.issue4,'\\~') c5, 
split(a.issue5,'\\~') c6  
from cima_scratch.CLNCL_ASSMT_ANS_DG a) B  
) A 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c1) c11 as n1 , date 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c2) c22 as n2 , issue1 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c3) c33 as n3 , issue2 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c4) c44 as n4 , issue3 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c5) c55 as n5 , issue4 
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(c6) c66 as n6 , issue5 
where n1=n2 and n1=n3 
and n1 = n4 and n1 = n5 and n1=n6 
) X
```

Below is the result of the above code, where ID = 2 have a single record instead of 3.

```
id       date              Issue1   Issue2   Issue3   Issue4    Issue5
1      01JAN1990            1         1       0        0         0             
1      31JAN1992            0         1       1        0         0
1      01APR1995            0         1       0        1         0
2      01JAN1992            0         0       1        1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that multiple lateral views work as cross join and where clause is to filter matching records only. If some lateral views produce less rows (issue5 for id=2 contains one element), where clause filters such rows out because they are not matching equality condition in the WHERE. The solution is to explode each array in a separate subquery and use LEFT JOINS. This will work correctly and **perform even better because no cross join happens**:

```
with your_data as(--initial data
select stack(2,
1, '01APR1995~31JAN1992~01JAN1990','0~0~1', '1~1~1', '0~1~0', '1~0~0', '0~0~0',
2, '01APR1996~31JAN1994~01JAN1992','0~0~0', '1~0~0', '1~1~1', '0~0~1', '0'
) as (id,dt,issue1,issue2,issue3,issue4,issue5)
),

c11 as(--first array
select  
a.id, c11.n1, c11.dt
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.dt,'~')) c11 as n1 , dt 
),

c22 as(--second array
select  
a.id, n2, c22.issue1
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.issue1,'~')) c22 as n2 , issue1 
),

c33 as(--third array
select  
a.id, n3, c33.issue2
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.issue2,'~')) c33 as n3 , issue2 
),

c44 as(--fourth array
select  
a.id, n4, c44.issue3
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.issue3,'~')) c44 as n4 , issue3 
),

c55 as(--fifth array
select  
a.id, n5, c55.issue4
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.issue4,'~')) c55 as n5 , issue4
),

c66 as(--6th array
select  
a.id, n6, c66.issue5
from your_data a 
LATERAL VIEW outer posexplode(split(a.issue5,'~')) c66 as n6 , issue5
)

select c11.id, n1, dt, issue1, issue2, issue3, issue4,issue5
from c11
     left join c22 on c11.id=c22.id and c11.n1=c22.n2
     left join c33 on c11.id=c33.id and c11.n1=c33.n3
     left join c44 on c11.id=c44.id and c11.n1=c44.n4
     left join c55 on c11.id=c55.id and c11.n1=c55.n5
     left join c66 on c11.id=c66.id and c11.n1=c66.n6
```

Result:

```
c11.id  n1  dt  issue1  issue2  issue3  issue4  issue5
1   0   01APR1995   0   1   0   1   0
1   1   31JAN1992   0   1   1   0   0
1   2   01JAN1990   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   01APR1996   0   1   1   0   0
2   1   31JAN1994   0   0   1   0   NULL
2   2   01JAN1992   0   0   1   1   NULL
```

Also tilde is not a special character in Java regexp and hence you do not need to escape it using double-slash.